# React Native: How to mute volume?

Tags: react-native

How do you mute the volume in React Native (specifically for Android)?

I am using https://github.com/oney/react-native-webrtc but disabling the audio tracks for that doesn't seem to do anything, so I want to just mute the phone completely.

Comment: please share the code

Comment: are you muting the remote source?

Comment: yeh. it looks like there's a n issue with that? https://github.com/oney/react-native-webrtc/issues/179

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: are you using the exact code?

Answer (score 1):

I used `offerToReceiveAudio : false` options to tell my PeerConnection that don't capture the audio track , in `createOffer` method .

For remote PeerConnection muting use this :

```
const pc = new RTCPeerConnection();
pc.createOffer({offerToReceiveVideo: true , offerToReceiveAudio: false}).then(sdpOffer=>{
    /// 
});
```

And use these params for the local media stream :

```
const mediaParams = {
    video : true ,
    audio : false ,
    options:{ muted : true }
};
getUserMedia(mediaParams, (error, stream) => {});
```

But I guess there's no certain way to mute the RTCView directly .

Comment: It doesn't work. Check this example here (line number 2636) https://github.com/inspify/lib-jitsi-meet/blob/bb37d23f37ee52990ceafe628e60780b33b22dad/modules/RTC/TraceablePeerConnection.js#L2636 Remote audio still receiving with no effect :(

Comment: if I set offerToReceiveAudio: false then I got black screen for remote video